# How can I make a TypeScript interface be one of 2 possible types where one is an array?

Tags: typescript

I am trying:

```
type SkuItem = ChildSkuItem & {
    childSkus: ChildSkuItem[],
};

type GetSkuItemsResponseType = Partial<Array<SkuItem>> & {
    errorCode?: string;
    errorMessage?: string;
}

Partial<GetSkuItemsErrSkuResponse> { }
export interface GetSkuItemsResponse extends GetSkuItemsResponseType { }
```

So `GetSkuItemsResponse` can either be an array of `SkuItem` or an object with properties `errorCode` and `errorMessage`.

However, this doesn't seem to work as I get:

```
 Argument of type '{ errorCode: string; errorMessage: string; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'GetSkuItemsResponse'.
  Type '{ errorCode: string; errorMessage: string; }' is missing the following properties from type 'GetSkuItemsResponse': length, pop, push, concat, and 26 more.
```

Comment: `&` doesn't mean "or", your types require a value to be *both* things.

Comment: Then how do I make it or? I tried `|`, but then I get `An interface can only extend an object type or intersection of object types with statically known members`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@shamoon - your type is fine for what you want if you use 'or' (|) instead of 'and' (&).  However, you can't then make it an interface, because classes can implement interfaces and can't easily implement one or other of two possible types.  Consider the code below - isn't this what you want?

```
interface ChildSkuItem {
    id: number;
    value?: string;
}
type SkuItem = ChildSkuItem & {
    childSkus: ChildSkuItem[],
};
type GetSkuItemsResponseType = Partial<Array<SkuItem>> | {
    errorCode?: string;
    errorMessage?: string;
}
// Can't make GetSkuItemsResponseType into an interface with this definition...
//interface GetSkuItemsResponse extends GetSkuItemsResponseType { }

function test() {
    const sku1: ChildSkuItem = { id: 1, value: "A Value" };
    const sku2: ChildSkuItem = { id: 2 };
    const sku3: ChildSkuItem = { id: 3 };
    const skuItem1: SkuItem = { id: 104, childSkus: [sku1, sku2] };
    const skuItem2: SkuItem = { id: 105, childSkus: [sku3] };
    // GetSkuItemsResponseType can have error info...
    const rt: GetSkuItemsResponseType = { errorCode: "100", errorMessage: "screwed" };
    // ...or it can have an array of skuItems
    const rt2: GetSkuItemsResponseType = [skuItem1, skuItem2];
};
```

Comment: Is there any way to say if it's NOT an array of `SkuItem`, then it MUST contain both `errorCode` and `errorMessage`?

Comment: As is, I have 2 errors: ` Property 'errorMessage' does not exist on type 'GetSkuItemsResponse'.` and ` Property 'errorMessage' does not exist on type '(SkuItem | undefined)[]'`

Comment: You can't have the right code: GetSkuItemsResponse is commented out above and doesn't exist at all!

Comment: Sorry - I'm using it within my context. It would be `GetSkuItemsResponseType`

Comment: Okay - So it seems to work locally, but when I use it upstream, that's when the errors occur

Comment: In answer to your earlier question re forcing errorCode and errorMessage, just do type GetSkuItemsResponseType = SkuItem[] | { errorCode: string; errorMessage: string; }.  That still allows empty arrays and null, but if you have an object it will have to have the two properties.